# How to fetch ERROR.docx from following string in SQL server \\Abc\Abc\Abc\Abc\Abc\Abc\ERROR.docx

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Just need to get the file name from above string in SQL SERVER ERROR.docx

Comment: hint....REVERSE, left, charindex, reverse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @SearchString VARCHAR(200)='aadsfasdf\asdfadsf\asdfadsf\ERROR.docx'
SELECT REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(@SearchString), CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(@SearchString))-1))
```

Comment: Yeah this is my hint personified.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was not using REVERSE :P

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @abc varchar(max)= '\\Abc\Abc\Abc\Abc\Abc\Abc\ERROR.docx'
select SUBSTRING(@abc,LEN(@abc)-9,LEN(@abc) )
```

Note this will work only for "Error.docx" 
Solution provided by @UnhandledExcepSean will work in all scenario's

Comment: This is pretty useless as it requires an exact length for the filename. You could have just written "select ERROR.docx".